# Python - opening cli/gui editors (vim, nano, geany...)

Tags: python

I'd like to open an editor (cli or gui-based) via Python script. I can do this with `os.system('vim file')`, but I'd also like to get output in case command fails. `subprocess.getstatusoutput('vim file')` doesn't work for opening programs with specific interface.

What's the best alternative?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you should really use `os.environ['EDITOR']` and not start some editor you choose.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not trying to force my grandma to use vi. I've written a little tools that parses a file containing list of editors and path aliases. E.g. I can do `ed httpd` and it will run `vim -arg1 -arg2 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.check_call([EDITOR, file_path])
```

will raise an `OSError` exception if `EDITOR` fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.execv(path, args)` if the command fails, an `OSError` will be thrown. You can find more details on [os.execv](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execv) documentation.

Comment: But if it succeeds, `os.execv` will not return to the Python interpreter.

Comment: He would like to get output in case command fails, I think that would work. But I agree with you, if he wants to get ALL output from that execution, it would not work properly.